# How to create memory DC with 24 bits per pixel?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I need it to work with RGB24 data using GDI functions (specifically StretchBlt() which is pretty fast) and I can't use CreateCompatibleDC() since it can create memory DC only with color depth of other DC. Usually it's used with screen DC (by transmitting NULL pointer to function) and usually screen has color depth of value 32. In addition I can't rely on it, 'coz if screen settings are changed my application probably won't work.

So I need some way to create memory DC with specific certain color depth. So far I've found only one way with using CreateDC() function but it requires many device specific parameters and seems somewhat unreliable for me. Moreover there are too many fields to be filled with appropriate values to call CreateDC().

Is there some easier way to create specific memory DC and not rely on some devices? Or even if to create memory DC with 24 bpp?

P.S. I need it for some fast graphics. I've tried manual adding alpha channel to bitmap for using it with compatible to screen 32bpp memory DC and it worked out, but was too slow. And as I said above, I can't rely on screen settings which can be changed.

Comment: Do you need to use gdi specifically? If not, have you investigated Direct2D? I haven't really done anything with D2D myself, only a little playing with rectangles and such like, so I don't know if it is suitable for your problem.

Comment: @markh44 I haven't tried Direct2D. I need to use graphics for drawing on Win components and in DirectDraw filters. Is Direct2D appropriate for using with windows controls?

Comment: I don't know if D2D can do that.  I would guess yes but it looks like you've got a solution so you'll probably want to stick with what you've got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bits-per-pixel does not really depend on a DC, but on the bitmap selected into it. Create a 24bpp bitmap with `CreateDIBSection` then select it into a memory DC.

Comment: I have tried that already. In this case SelectObject() returns NULL which means an error occurred. I believe DC's and bitmap's bits per pixel must be equal because the same thing with the same bitmap worked out when I manually added alpha channel. Maybe it's all because I create bitmap using CreateBitmapIndirect()?

Comment: Is bitmap object valid, not NULL?

Comment: Yep, HBITMAP was created by CreateBitmapIndirect() from filled BITMAP struct and it's not null. And if I save it in file for debug purposes it's a valid 24bpp bitmap.

Comment: Use CreateDIBSection, not CreateBitmapIndirect. The latter creates DDB (device-dependent bitmap) and may be the reason why it cant be selected into a screen-compatible DC.

Comment: Seems it can do the thing I need. Thanks.